# Check for repeated values in a particular key of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array having two different prices with the same id.
Let it be...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [price] => 3800 [id] => 400015 )  
        [1] => Array ( [price] => 3700 [id] => 400015 )
        [2] => Array ( [price] => 3300 [id] => 400018 )
        [3] => Array ( [price] => 3000 [id] => 400018 )
        [4] => Array ( [price] => 3100 [id] => 400020 )
        [5] => Array ( [price] => 3400 [id] => 400020 ))
```

I need to display them as

```
 id:400015, Price=3800-3700
 id:400018, Price=3000-3600
 id:400020, Price=3100-3400
```

Comment: Loop the array in loop and push the elements as key for Id and Prince for respective ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below if array_column doesn't support

```
$arr = Array ( '0' => Array ( 'price' => 3800, 'id' => 400015 )  ,
        '1' => Array ( 'price' => 3700, 'id' => 400015 ),
        '2' => Array ( 'price' => 3300, 'id' => 400018 ),
        '3' => Array ( 'price' => 3000, 'id' => 400018 ),
        '4' => Array ( 'price' => 3100, 'id' => 400020 ),
        '5' => Array ( 'price' => 3400, 'id' => 400020 ),);

        $new_arr =array();
        foreach($arr as $key=>$row){
            if(isset($new_arr[$row['id']])){
                $new_arr[$row['id']]= $new_arr[$row['id']].'-'.$row['price'];
            }else{
                $new_arr[$row['id']]=$row['price'];
            }
        }

        foreach($new_arr as $key=>$row){
            echo 'id:'.$key.', Price = '.$row.'<br>';
        }
```

Comment: Works perfect, but, i have to sort the price values too

Comment: update if statement with this : $new_arr[$row['id']]= (($new_arr[$row['id']]<$row['price'])?($new_arr[$row['id']].'-'.$row['price']) : ($row['price'].'-'.$new_arr[$row['id']])) ;

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop array and create new array which will be easy to create output you want to show

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($main as $key=>$val){
    $newArray[$val['id']][] = $val['price'];
}

foreach ($newArray as $key=>$val){
    sort($val,1);
    echo 'id: '.$key.', Price='.implode('-', $val).'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: It is returning the values in the order they were in the array, but, I need to sort the price values too

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala - You can short $val in second loop before implode to show range in right order : $val = short($val,1);

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala - I have edited answer, you can check that for sorting.

Comment: And now it is sorting every value in the array, not just the values with the same id

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and print out the respective `id` and `price`. Not too sure what you are doing with the price subtraction but this should give you what you need.

```
$array = array(array('price'=>3800, 'id'=>40015),
               array('price'=>3700 , 'id'=>40001),
               array('price'=>3800, 'id'=>400015),
               array('price'=>3300 , 'id'=>400018),
               array('price'=>3000 , 'id'=>400018),
               array('price'=>3100 , 'id'=>400020),
               array('price'=>3400 , 'id'=>400020));

asort($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo 'id: '.$value['id'].', Price='.$value['price'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: That's not price subtraction, I am trying to sort the price values from low to high

Comment: I've edited my post, it now sorts the array by price before printing it out.

Comment: Not just sorting, I need to display the prices of single `id`

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a little bit of variance, and use a PHP7 feature:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a['price'] <=> $b['price']; });
$maxPrices = array_column($data, 'price', 'id');

usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $b['price'] <=> $a['price']; });
$minPrices = array_column($data, 'price', 'id');

foreach($minPrices as $id => $minPrice) {
    echo 'id:', $id, ', Price=', $minPrice, '-', $maxPrices[$id], PHP_EOL;
}
```

This uses `usort()` to order the array by maximum price (using the new "spaceship" operator); then `array_column()` to create an array of id's and max prices, as where there are matching id's then the price will be overridden by the previous values so that only the highest value matching each `id` remains in the `$maxPrices` array; then does similarly for minimum values.

Finally the loop iterates over the min array, fetching each id and minimum price in turn, and does an id lookup to get the maximum price to display

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/l0oQU)

Note that use of the spaceship operator does require PHP7